# Ext JS Dependent combo box

Tags: extjs, coldfusion, cfquery

I am new to extJS, and trying to implement the following functionality:

I have two select drop down menus, transformed using extJS. How can I make sure that if a value in one combo box is selected, the other value should be set back to some default value?

Thanks.

Edited: Code till now:

```
Ext.onReady(function(){ 

var converted = new Ext.form.ComboBox({ 

    typeAhead: true, 
    triggerAction: 'all', 
    transform:'id_Select1', 
    width:600, 
    forceSelection:true, 
    emptyText:'Select' 

}); 

var convertedCdr = new Ext.form.ComboBox({ 
    typeAhead: true, 
    triggerAction: 'all', 
    transform:'id_select2', 
    width:600, 
    forceSelection:true, 
    emptyText:'Select' 
}); 
});
```

I am using ColdFusion to query the database and populate the drop down menus:

```
<cfquery name="getData1" datasource="abc">
   SELECT * FROM table1
</cfquery>

<cfquery name="getData2" datasource="abc">
   SELECT * FROM table2
</cfquery>

<select name="select1" id="select1">
  <cfoutput query="getData1">
       <option value="#getData1.Id#">#getData1.name#</option>
  </cfoutput>
</select>

 <select name="select2" id="select1">
  <cfoutput query="getData2">
       <option value="#getData2.Id#">#getData2.name#</option>
  </cfoutput>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDITED - I haven't used CFM... you'll need to figure out how to load your CF using data stores to use this technique.**

You will need to add a listener for the select event on the combo:

```
xtype: 'combo',
id   : 'firstComboID',
listeners: {
  select: function(combo,  record,  index ) {
    var selVal = Ext.getCmp('firstComboID').getValue();
    var secondCombo = Ext.getCmp('secondComboID');
    secondCombo.store.reload({params: {yourParameterName: selVal}});
}
```

Basically you are doing the following here:

1. Get the value selected in the first combo
2. Get a reference to the second combo's data store
3. Reload the store of the second combo box using the selected value from the first combo

Comment: Here is the code I have till now

`Ext.onReady(function(){ var converted = new Ext.form.ComboBox({ typeAhead: true, triggerAction: 'all', transform:'id_Select1', width:600, forceSelection:true, emptyText:'Select' } });

var convertedCdr = new Ext.form.ComboBox({ typeAhead: true, triggerAction: 'all', transform:'id_select2', width:600, forceSelection:true, emptyText:'Select' });

});

I have two select drop downs populated from database: Not sure if combo.store would work in my case?

Comment: Can you edit your question with your source code using the code formatting in the WYSIWYG editor please?

Where do you your combo boxes get their data from then?  I don't see any configuration options.

Comment: I need to see how you are loading the data... When you use **transform** in the configuration, the DOM elements are converted to an ArrayStore automatically.

Can you edit your question to show the layout and how the data is loaded?

Comment: I updated my question with html code too. I hvae another question. In javascript, I use document.all.select1.value to get the value of an element. What is the equivalent in extJS?

Comment: Ext.getCmp('fieldDomID').value

Comment: I don't suppose you're using Spring MVC also are you?  I'm a bit unsure of how to do the conversions between ColdFusion and ExtJS... All my experience has been using Java, JSP, or PHP calls

Comment: No, I am not using Spring MVC. Can you direct me to good extJS tutorials for beginners, explaining basic stuff like getting and setting element values, manipulating form elements etc?

Comment: Please accept my answer while you're at it.  I feel my help has been sufficient to get the bump in reputation...